# Why do dict from list assigned from last element?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase
>>> from random import shuffle
>>> shuffle(alp)
>>> alp
['n', 'c', 'q', 'l', 's', 't', 'w', 'a', 'o', 'r', 'g', 'u', 'd', 'm', 'k', 
 'p', 'x', 'v', 'z', 'y', 'j', 'h', 'i', 'f', 'e', 'b']
>>> ck = {x:alp.pop() for x in ascii_lowercase}
>>> ck
{'a': 'b', 'b': 'e', 'c': 'f', 'd': 'i', 'e': 'h', 'f': 'j', 'g': 'y', 'h': 
 'z', 'i': 'v', 'j': 'x', 'k': 'p', 'l': 'k', 'm': 'm', 'n': 'd', 'o': 'u', 
 'p': 'g', 'q': 'r', 'r': 'o', 's': 'a', 't': 'w', 'u': 't', 'v': 's', 'w': 
 'l', 'x': 'q', 'y': 'c', 'z': 'n'}
```

What make's and why alp list assigned to ck  from the last list element of alp? Like "a:b b:e..."

Comment: Because that's what pop does...

Answer (score 0):

Because `list.pop()` returns and removes last element of the list. If you want to return and remove first element you can use `list.pop(0)`.

See documentation for additional infromation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html